# Deploying my application

Tags: directory-structure

When deploying my application under linux, where do I put my libraries, executable and the desktop entry file? And what about other files my program needs? For example background pictures, audio files etc.

I heard that I put my **executable** file in the `/usr/bin/` folder, my **libraries** in the `/opt/<myapp>/lib/` folder and my **desktop entry** file in `/usr/share/applications/` folder. Is that correct?

But where is the general place for application resources?

Is that everything I need to care of when deploying my application or are there other steps I am missing?

Comment: The question is not precise. Are you building a binary package for installation into the system, or planning to do a local installation? I assume the former, which is consistent with most of your paths except the `/opt` one. The LHS says `/opt` should not be used for binary packages that are part of the system.

Comment: There are several Q's that are related to this topic on the site. The FHS is what often is referred to when determining where installed assets go: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74646/difference-between-lib-lib32-lib64-libx32-and-libexec/74652#74652. Also take a look at the man page: `man hier`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) specifies where to put files.

If you're installing files outside of the package manager, always put them under `/usr/local` or under `/opt`. **Never touch anything under `/usr` except via the package manager, except for things under `/usr/local`**.

- `/usr/local/bin`: executables intended to be executed by users (interactively or from scripts)
- `/usr/local/lib`: libraries available to many programs, not just yours
- `/usr/local/lib/YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME`: any other architecture-dependent files
- `/usr/local/share/doc`: documentation (except in man and info format)
- `/usr/local/share/info`: documentation in info format
- `/usr/local/share/man/man*`: man pages
- `/usr/local/share/YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME`: any other architecture-independent files

These days, the separation of the `share` area which contains architecture-independent files isn't very important. It was devised back when hard disks were smaller and it was important to save space by not storing architecture-independent files twice in heterogeneous networks. You can skip this distinction if you like and put everything under `lib/YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME`.

If you prefer to use `/opt`, put everything under `/opt/YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME`, and make symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` (and `/usr/local/share/man/man*` and `/usr/local/share/info` if you provide documentation in man and info format) so that users can invoke your program.

If you make deb or rpm packages, put files under `/usr` instead of `/usr/local`. Check each distribution's documentation for its particularities.